# Non-constant holomorphic mapping $f:M_{1} \longrightarrow M_{2}$ between compact Riemann surface

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

> Consider non-constant holomorphic mapping $f:M_{1} \longrightarrow M_{2}$ between compact Riemann surfaces, then 
>   $$ g(M_{1})\geq g(M_{2}),$$
>   where denotes the genus of $M_{1}$ by $g(M_{1})$, and the same $g(M_{2})$.

I try to use the conclusion

> $$H^{1} \cong H_{dR}^{1}(M),$$
>   where $H^{1}:=\{$Harmonic 1-forms of Riemann surface$\}$, and $H_{dR}^{1}(M)$ is the de Rham cohomology.

By this conclusion, $2g(M_{1})= \dim H^{1}= \dim H_{dR}^{1}(M)$, which means $g$ is a topology invariance. Moreover, $H^{1}=\mathscr{H}\oplus \bar{\mathscr{H}}$, where $\mathscr{H}$ is the holomorphic 1-form and $\bar{\mathscr{H}}$ conjugate. Hence, $$g(M_{1})= \dim \mathscr{H}$$

My question is why $\dim \mathscr{H}$ of $M_{1}$ is greater than $M_{2}$?

$\textbf{New edited}$

@Laurent Moret-Bailly
Following this idea, if $\omega$ is a holomorphic 1-form on $M_{2}$, and consider the pullback of $\omega$: 
$$f^{*}: H^{0}(M_{2}) \longrightarrow H^{0}(M_{1}),$$
then $f^{*}\omega$ is a holomorphic 1-form on $M_{1}$.

How about the next? Is there a related between $(f^{*}\omega)$ and $f^{*}(\omega)$?

Comment: It's not along the lines you proposed, but Riemann-Hurwitz formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula) can be used here.

Comment: In the same spirit as @PseudoNeo, I suggest looking at the map $f^*:H^0(\Omega^1_{M_2})\to H^0(\Omega^1_{M_1})$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Do you mean my new edited?

Comment: @PseudoNeo I think my way is other interpretation of Riemann-Hurwitz formula.

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui: It suffices to observe that this $f^*$ is injective.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Riemann-Hurwitz Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula),

to conclude that $2g(M_1) - 2 = deg(f)(2g(M_2) - 2) + deg R_f \geq2g(M_2)-2$.

---

Following @Laurent Moret-Bailly 's idea, we can show that $f^*$ is injective.

Suppose $f^*\omega = 0$, i.e. $\forall p\in X, v\in T_pX,f^*\omega(v)=0$

If $p$ is not a ramification point, $f$ induces an isomorphism on tangent spaces, and hence $\omega|_{f(p)} = 0 $.

So $\omega|_q = 0$ for all but finite $q\in Y$, and thus $\omega = 0$.

Comment: Yes.You are right. But I have known this method. And I do not want to use this conclusion, but the definition.

Comment: Please consider the idea is presented by @Laurent Moret-Bailly

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your new answer!